# Server Error in '/' Application. Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, web-applications

I am trying to make this work for an assignment, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I am making a web application in Visual Studio 2012. I get this error when I try to post the form to the database. I am a total noob and this is the first time I have ever posted here so please bear with me. I've checked spelling on column names and everything seems to be in order.

```
Server Error in '/genericname' Application.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 18:         myCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullText", txtFullText.Text)   
Line 19:         myCon.Open()
Line 20:         myCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
Line 21:         myCon.Close()
Line 22: 
Source File: F:\Documents\School\WebAppDevelopment\Assignment1\****\admin\add-article.aspx.vb    Line: 20
```

Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1754082
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295874
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1325
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   admin_add_article.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Documents\School\WebAppDevelopment\Assignment1\CarlsonDavidLab2\admin\add-article.aspx.vb:20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9634378
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Here is my code:

[image]
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra `,` after the `subDate`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan, Eagle Eye ... LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `,` after the `subDate` in this line:

```
mySQL &= "summary, fullText, subDate,) VALUES (@headline, @postDate, @author, @category, "
```

Additional note, instead of using `AddWithValue`, you should use `Parameters.Add` and specify the underlying database datatype.

More on this [here.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: You, sir, are a champion amongst mortal men, and StackOverflow is the Bee's Knees.